# How can I use the iOS list icon in my app

Tags: ios

I'm making an app and I want to use an icon that I find in many areas of iOS. It's the list icon and can be seen in Apple's default calendar (iOS8 and iOS9)

See images below first one is from Apple calendar. Second one is from Microsoft OneNote app

[image: calendar app]
[image: onenote]

Comment: Not sure about the official icon, but just do a Google Image search for "list icon" and you'll find plenty of near-perfect versions to use yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that. But if the icon is available in the system somehow I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after downloading and running iOS-Artwork-Extractor on iOS 8.4, I found that you can find and extract tons of iOS icons embedded in the system.

I was eventually able to find the list icon. It's named UIButtonBarListIcon@2x.png

You can find the iOS-Artwork-Extractor here https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

This project will let you download "all" icons and save them to your Mac's Desktop. From there you can search through all the icons in your Mac's finder. Pretty neat project.

Answer (score 3):

That specific icon is not a `UIBarButtonSystemItem`. You can see the full list of what icons there are in the [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem).

Here is a link to an [Icon Set](https://dribbble.com/shots/1925069-Lynny-Icon-Set-Free) that seems to have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks the reference to the links! I like those icons. I think I will use them. Just thought I'd ask on SO about a default icon. Because for example, MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem is not a UIBarButtonItem, but I was able to find documentation on how to get that icon. It wasn't very obvious to me that I needed to use MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem for the location arrow.

Comment: That is a good point, I forgot about other system buttons that inherit from UIBarButtonItem (like MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem). I think in this case you will need a custom icon however. Let me know if you do find a system button with that icon though

Comment: I will definitely let you know.